# Error:(25, 46) error: @InjectViews must be a List or array

Tags: android, butterknife

```
public class DailyForecastActivity extends ListActivity {

private Day[] mDays;

@InjectViews(android.R.id.list) ListView mListView;
@InjectViews(android.R.id.empty) TextView mEmptyTextView;
```

but when I debug , ı get error like that

```
Error:(25, 46) error: @InjectViews must be a List or array. (brah.mb.hanifiui.DailyForecastActivity.mListView)
Error:(26, 47) error: @InjectViews must be a List or array. (brah.mb.hanifiui.DailyForecastActivity.mEmptyTextView)
```

what is the error. if any information u need , ı can edit again.tnx.

Comment: Is that injection library a roboguice or a butterKnife? You should mention it in tags. In any case the error is clear, you should use `@InjectView` annotations istead of `@InjectViews`, because second one is for array of views

Comment: ahh ok tnx so much :)  ıt fixed

Comment: please you need use anotation InjectView and not the anotation InjectViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using ButterKnife library. '@InjectViews' was used to inject several views as array.

eg :

```
@InjectViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

@InjectViews should be used only on List type or on an array of view objects. Other implementations are restricted.

You can also look at working code sample [here](https://github.com/codeherenow/expert-android-development/blob/master/ButterKnife/app/src/main/java/com/codeherenow/butterknife/BillingShippingActivity.java).

So, you cannot use it the way you have defined, the error clearly states that, you need to use list or array. Moreover, look into new [document](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), the thing that you are trying to do is simply the very first example, simply use @BindView, and if you want to bind multiple similar views at once, search for @BindViews on the same page itself.

Hope It helps !

Comment: yessss, definitelt :) tncx so muchhh it is much better explanation for me in order to fix problemmm :)